# Django, GDAL and CircleCI 2

Tags: django, docker, gdal, geodjango, circleci

I have a Django app configured with GeoDjango that is failing on CircleCI 2.0 builds with the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library. Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

However, when I remove `'django.contrib.gis'` from `DJANGO_APPS` in `settings.py` the build runs successfully.

Are there additional steps for configuring GDAL in CircleCI outside of the postgres and GDAL docker images? I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that GDAL would be found after the docker image was installed. Below is my `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.3

      - image: circleci/postgres:10.1-postgis
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=ubuntu
        - POSTGRES_DB=myapp_test

      - image: geodata/gdal

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ./venv
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}

      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py test
          environment:
            DATABASE_URL: "postgres://ubuntu@localhost:5432/myapp_test"

      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports
          destination: test-reports
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
```

right where you run `pip install`:

```
  - run:
      name: install dependencies
      command: |
        python3 -m venv venv
        . venv/bin/activate
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
```

Comment: This worked for me using the circleci/python:3.6 image, although I had to use sudo:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal`

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Docker, but I've had my fair share of issues installing GDAL. Typically, when I have had to setup an environment which required GDAL in Django, I've followed the following steps (roughly).

First I run these commands, to install the GDAL library and set up the headers before installing the python library:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
gdal-config --version  # to see what version of GDAL you have
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

Next, somewhere inside my reqs.txt there's this line:

```
GDAL==2.1.0  # replace the version with the one you get from gdal-config
```

I install the packages in my reqs.txt:

```
pip install -r reqs.txt
```

Usually this is what it takes for me to set up GDAL so that I'm able to use `django.contrib.gis`.

I hope this is of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your third image is running in a separate container and GDAL is not available in the first one.

I made geodjango tests running using this docker image [`wooyek/geodjango`](https://hub.docker.com/r/wooyek/geodjango) from Docker Hub.

Here is the beginning of my `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # image with pre-installed geodjango libs
      - image: wooyek/geodjango

      # postgis database
      - image: circleci/postgres:alpine-postgis-ram
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: circle_test
```